# How to create image slider using Sqlite database?

Tags: android, android-imageview

How to create image slider use of sqlite?
not using static images but image come from gallary

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like [this](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) slider. It gets a hashmap of images. Load the hashmap with your gallery images instead of static ones.